# Changing title, value not working in nsbutton, nstextfield

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nstextfield, nsbutton, nswindowcontroller

I have a window which contains two nsbutton and a nstextfield(label). In windowcontroller implementation class windowdidload inside I have set button title using setTitle and set label string value using setStringvalue.

I have try to modify button title and label string value in some other class which is not working. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the class is allocated or nil in other class. if the class is nil we can't change the button label tile and textfield string value.